# HHVM 502 Bad gateway - Fedora 21

Tags: nginx, hhvm

G'day.

I have fedora 21, HHVM version 3.7. My issue unfortunately is that I can start the service, and I can access my pages no issue. However if I consistently refresh the page, the HHVM crashes and upon checking the status, it returns this error:

[image]

The HHVM error log returns:

```
Unable to open pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for write
```

Now I can restart the server and it works fine, but only after a hand full of requests it will crash as above.

PHP-FPM is not running and nothing except HHVM is running on port 9000

Here is some config info

HHVM - server.ini

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific

hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.source_root = /srv/www
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.level = Error
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
```

HHVM - service

```
[Unit]
Description=HipHop Virtual Machine (FCGI)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hhvm --config /etc/hhvm/server.ini --user hhvm --mode daemon -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9000
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

NGINX - site file

```
##NGINX STUFF
    location ~ \.php$ {
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index bootstrap.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
##MORE NGINX STUFF
```

So from the info provided, is there any hint as to what could be the issue?

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple permission issue like your log mentioned. You have no access to the pid folder to generate the pid file.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/run/hhvm
```

I had the same problem on Ubuntu.

[HHVM Unable to read pid file /var/run/hhvm/pid for any meaningful pid after reboot](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/hvvm-unable-to-read-pid-file-var-run-hhvm-pid-for-any-meaningful-pid-after-reboot)

Another problem when you have a lot of requests can be the **max open files** limit. When you come over the limit HHVM crashes. Normally you should see that error in your log and you can increase that limit.

https://serverfault.com/questions/679408/hhvm-exit-after-too-many-open-files

Here is my question on ServerFault.

Comment: Cheers man. I'll have a look when I get home and let you know how I go

Comment: Hi Stony, unfortunately the solution didn't work the same issue is occuring

Comment: Hmm it's very difficult without any logs and informations.

Comment: Ok. So I disabled jit and it seems to work fine. So there appears to be an issue with jit. I did some googling and people have suggested either a bug in jit or memory leak issues. So I'm going to investigate these issues further. THanks for your help anyway

Comment: Perhaps you can setup a local system and test it with another distribution like Debian or Ubuntu or something else and try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Indeed, I'll give it ago

Comment: Hey Stony, I thought I might let you know. I uninstalled and removed the repo I was using and tried a different repo. The ulyaoth I think it is, works perfectly fine!